Can I have multiple guardians of faith?
I noticed something with "guardian of faith", both in 2014 and 2024's basic rules.

A Large spectral guardian appears and hovers for the duration in an unoccupied space that you can see within range. The guardian occupies that space and is invulnerable, and it appears in a form appropriate for your deity or pantheon.
Any enemy that moves to a space within 10 feet of the guardian for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there makes a Dexterity saving throw, taking 20 Radiant damage on a failed save or half as much damage on a successful one. The guardian vanishes when it has dealt a total of 60 damage.
Duration: 8 hours

It's not concentration. Also, it doesn't say anything about disappearing if I summon another.
So can I summon as many of them as I want, provided I have enough spell slots?

"The guardian vanishes when it has dealt a total of 60 damage" - that means actually dealt, so 3 successful (failed save) attacks or up to 6 attacks with successful saves, you agree?

@Flynxer yep! I'm just talking about if they didn't deal damage at all

Yes
There is nothing in the rules that limits or prevents multiple castings of Guardian of Faith. However, some might stipulate that additional instances of the spell after the first would be nullified whenever they overlap, because of the clause

The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don’t combine... (2014)

under Combining Magical Effects. And,

...the effects of the same spell cast multiple times don’t combine. (2024)

The rule itself inherently implies that the same spell can be cast multiple times. But, it stipulates the effects of those spells won't combine.
Strictly speaking, a spell's entry describes its "effects":

The rest of a spell entry describes the spell’s effect. (2014)

and

The effects of a spell are detailed after its duration entry. (2024)

In my opinion, Guardians of Faith doesn't have "effects" in that sense that could "combine" (i.e. buffs/debuffs), so each instantiation should be treated independently; but, there is room to argue either way, so you should talk to your GM.

Do you have an analogous reference for 5e 2024? I think you’re right, but a reference to the 2024 analog of the combining effects rule would really round out this answer.

Because the guardian takes up space and thus can't be cast a second time on the same square, I see no reasonable argument that the effects should combine at all. The "occupies space" part of this spell is pretty important!

@MichaelW., Cast on adjacent squares, the 10 ft radius beyond the Large, occupied space could overlap, though. I was imagining a "minefield" of SGs.

Yeah, the one thing that would fail to "combine" would be the overlap when they are near each other. A common sense reading of these rules would say they only take 20 damage not 40 or 60 in the "minefield".

@jerclarke,  I think it would be reasonable to say the 40/60 damage is legit. But, it would also be reasonable not to, as you've indicated.
